# Telegram API - InlineKeyboardMarkup - не могу найти библиотеку (JDK11)

Tags: java, telegram, библиотеки, jdk11

Не могу найти класс *InlineKeyboardMarkup* в библиотеке TELEGRAM API *telegrambots-4.1-jar-with-dependencies*. Кто знает - скажите путь или где скачать библиотеку с этим классом, буду благодарен). В гугле не нашёл ответ на этот вопрос...

Весь импорт библии:

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Message;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
```

Использую JDK 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;
```